# Multiply factors from nested lists

Tags: python

I am trying to multiply factors from the first nested list with the second nested list. The result I get is [0,0,0,0]. Help appreciated.

```
Faktorer = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]

res = []


for Faktorer[0][i] in Faktorer:
    for Faktorer[1][j] in Faktorer:
        res.append(i*j)


print(res)
```

Comment: Where are `i` and `j` defined? What is the desired output?

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

Using a nested loop is right, but your syntax is all mixed up.

```
>>> Faktorer = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
>>> res = []
>>> for i in Faktorer[0]:
...     for j in Faktorer[1]:
...         res.append(i * j)
...
>>> res
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

You can also do this as a list comprehension like this:

```
>>> [i * j for i in Faktorer[0] for j in Faktorer[1]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

If `Faktorer` had an arbitrary number of sublists (making it impossible to do this with a fixed number of nested loops), or if you just didn't want to use nested loops, you could use `product` to generate the combinations of all the factors and `reduce` to multiply them:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [reduce(int.__mul__, f, 1) for f in product(*Faktorer)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am struggling with the syntaxes.

Answer (score 0):

What you described in a Kronecker product. If you are allowed to use libraries, you could use `numpy.kron`:

```
import numpy as np

res = list(np.kron(Faktorer[0], Faktorer[1]))

print(res)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81, 90, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Comment: Thank you. Did not know about that